# calculate the average( csv.file with python)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do I calculate the average (mean) exam score of the students when I have a score for 3 subject exams on my csv.file with python

There is my csv.file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ7Uj.png)
As you can see there are scores for 3 subjects and I want to calculate all the 3 and get the average (mean) exam scores
And I'm using the jupyter notebook and tried some solutions on the internet and doesn't fit.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r61eD.png)
(I'm a beginner in using Python)

Code for calculating the average (mean)

Comment: Your CSV file has a header row.  You need to skip that row.  You can check whether the first item starts with a number, and do `continue` if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use pandas to read the csv file and calculate the average of each subject a.k.a column and have it stored as a variable.

df_input = pd.read_csv("C:\test.csv")
math_score = df_input["MathScore"].mean()
print(math_score)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is for only one subject and I need for exam scores all the 3 subjects

Comment: @Jehan: You can repeat the same template for other two subjects too.                  
**avg_reading_score = df_input["ReadingScore"].mean()                                            
 avg_writing_score = df_input["WritingScore"].mean()**

Answer (score 0):

```
import statistics
# First, create a list of the student's scores, like this: 
studentScores [78, 85, 83] # Order does not matter.
# We will now make a variable including the mean.
averageScore = statistics.mean(studentScores) 
print(averageScore)
# Done!
```

Comment: But I have a lot of variables in my file.csv that I can't write a list for every variable like you I need a way to calculate the average of all exam scores